# Merge all the dependent assemblies to Exe on build

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dll-injection

I have been searching from long time about how to merge dlls to project output exe.

I installed **[Vitevic Assembly Embedder](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a7196a81-67fc-4a26-a88a-b68ef31c2266)** but when the project is built it still leaves some of the dll files as it is.

Since i heared about **ILMerge** but I could not found any useful support.
I need a tool that can merge all the dlls.

Comment: I've always used Costura Fody for DLL merging.

Comment: @Patrick I followed Coustra Foudy from [here](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/01/bundling-all-your-assemblies-into-one-or-alternative-to-ilmerge/)  It is excellent! Thank you legend

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do:

1. Store all dlls inside some folder inside solution (like "libs").
2. Inside VS change "Build Action" for all dlls to "Embedded Resource" - this will "store" actuall files inside exe.
3. Place this code in the Main method, or anywhere before you use any of the external assemblies:

   `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;`

Also this:

```
    private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        var dllName = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";

        var resources = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(s => s.EndsWith(dllName));
        if (resources.Any())
        {
            var resourceName = resources.First();
            using (var stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                if (stream == null) return null;
                var block = new byte[stream.Length];

                try
                {
                    stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
                    return Assembly.Load(block);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                catch (BadImageFormatException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what about System.http etc and other system references? Will it work?

Comment: how can i refer the assemblies ? Should i browse for each assembly and then add that?

Comment: @Umar it will work with any dll you provide hence `assemblyName.Name + ".dll";`